# Why does my Django form data not appear in the database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, forms

I try to develop a simple input form to save a deposit for a fishing vessel. The vessel and the net are tables in the database. There is no error when the form is submitted but there is nothing happening in the background. I use a PostgreSQL database with PgAdmin for insights.I am a little bit stuck since it's my first time working with Django.

I tried adding the dep_id field into the form but it did not change anything.

[forms.py]

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Deposit


class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    dep_date = forms.DateField()
    harbour = forms.CharField()
    vessel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vessel.objects.all())
    net = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Net.objects.all())
    amount = forms.DecimalField()

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ['dep_date', 'harbour', 
                    'vessel', 'net', 
                    'amount']
```

[models.py]

```py
from django.db import models

class Vessel(models.Model):
    VID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    vessel_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    WIN = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    IRCS = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    vessel_type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    fishing_methods = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    length = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    
    auth_period_from = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auth_period_to = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Net(models.Model):
    net_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default = None)
    prod_date = models.DateField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fishing_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)


class Deposit(models.Model):
    dep_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    dep_date = models.DateField()
    harbour = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(Vessel, to_field='VID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    net = models.ForeignKey(Net, to_field='net_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

[views.py]

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Vessel
from .forms import UploadForm

def put_deposit(request):
    if request.POST:    
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)
        print(request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        redirect(index)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form' : UploadForm})
```

[upload.html]

```html
<p> Upload </p>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'put_deposit' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{form}}
    <button> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Maybe I have any kind of dependency wrong or is it a problem with a key?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The fields on your form are [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/) you should use [form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/) - `forms.DateField()` instead of `forms.DateInput()` for example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the fields but unfortunately, the problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/), but then adding fields which are already in your model to the form as if it were a regular [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/).  You *can* add *extra* fields to your ModelForm by doing so, but since you are adding the *same* fields, perhaps that is why it is not validating.

Suggestion:  Try

(1) What @Milo has already suggested to print out `form.errors` to see if the form is indeed valid or not,

(2) Change your form to:

```py
class UploadForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ['dep_date', 'harbour', 
                    'vessel', 'net', 
                    'amount']
```

(3) Also, although I do not think this is what is causing the error, your view has some issues.  Try:

```py
def put_deposit(request):
    form = UploadForm(request.POST or None)
    print(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        redirect('index')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: Now it's working, thanks a million! I think the issue was a combination of the widget fields and the model form.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a troubleshooting suggestion, but hard to show in a comment.  Your form might not be validating for some reason or another - add this to see if there are errors:

```
def put_deposit(request):
    if request.POST:    
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)
        print(request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors) # add these two lines
        redirect(index)
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form' : UploadForm})
```